# Insert row PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone spot my mistake here? Can't seem to see what is wrong. (these values are just test values)
The database connection is OK.

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `test2` (`usrname`, `resname`,` type`, `pricerange`, `vicinity`, `lat`, `lng`)
    VALUES ('shyt',
            'shytyou',
            'rubbish',
            'hyper',
            'starwars',
            23,
            321)" );
```

Comment: can you describe what's going wrong?

Comment: It's most likely ` type`. This is the kind of stuff you figure out by enabling MySQL errors.

Comment: try `mysqli_query() or die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: thanks @Joost ... what a disaster I am LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is having a space in type field

```
` type`
```

should be

```
`type`
```

Comment: gosh yes.. thanks for saving my soul!!!